# How to get "Repro Steps" of a list of work items?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

My team has been using VSTS for 8 months. Now, Our customer is asking to get "Repro Steps" of the work items in VSTS.
Is there any way to get the content of "Repro Steps" without the HTML format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the Repro Steps value is the rich text that can contain image etc…. So, the value is incorrect if just return the data without HTML format.

However, you can remove HTML tag programing.

Simple code:

```
 public static string StripHTML(string input)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
        }



var u = new Uri("[collection URL]"");
 VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("[user name]", "[password]")));
 var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
            var workitemClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
            var workitem = workitemClient.GetWorkItemAsync(96).Result;
            object repoValue = workitem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps"];
            string repoValueWithOutformat = StripHTML(repoValue.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you @starain-MSFT, but, does it work with images in "Repro Steps"?

Comment: @shinjidev The value of image in Repro Steps is the URL with img tag, you can get the image by requesting that URL (e.g. browser in IE). Note: The URL is encoded, you need to replace &amp; to &

Comment: Nice @starain-MSFT. It worked really good. Thank you very much :)